# How snowball does delta data migration

Tags: amazon-web-services

When we transfer huge amount of data from the on-premise data center to snowball and dispatch the snowball device to AWS data centers, during the data transfer period, there will be a good amount of real-time data that will continue to get recorded in the customer data center. Let's say snowball will take 2 days to ship data to designated AWS region data center. How does AWS ensure, this 2 days data recorded in the on-prem data center is also migrated into the cloud so there is no additional data left in the customer data center and 100% data is migrated? What options AWS has to address this?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the kind of data you are talking about, but the general strategy would be using Snowball to transfer all the bulk data until a particular moment in time, and from that moment in time start shipping the data that gets into your data centre to AWS directly over the network.

The problem Snowball solves is transferring large amounts of data that wouldn't be efficient over the network, but for all the new data, you can send a copy to the AWS in real time or at regular intervals. The size of that data should be small enough so network transfer works fine.

Regarding data migration AWS has [many different services](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-data-migration/) and it really depends on your specific requirements.

A very common setup is to use at the very least direct connect, so you can have a dedicated connection to Amazon's data centres. If the data you have is small enough, you can just use simple tools to send the data to S3 or to a kinesis firehose.

For more complex scenarios, you might want to use maybe a storage gateway, that sits in your data centre and allows seamless integration with many data and file stores on AWS.

So the details would depend on each use case, but the answer would be a combination of the technologies mentioned on the [Cloud Data Migration page](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-data-migration/)

Comment: if you want more information about data migration options, you can take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMgRLUm_R9I